# Why can I not change the value of a listed plugin setting with SBT?

Tags: scala, plugins, configuration, sbt

I'm using the [sbt-start-script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) plugin to build my project (although I think the question is more generally applicable than that; it just happens to provide a concrete example). I want to change the value of the `start-script-name` setting (the relevant source file defining the settings can be found [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script/blob/ee53d1a7b1a14ef7b9a4117999bef92342ce464e/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/SbtStartScript.scala)). Per the docs, I have added the following lines to my `build.sbt` and it creates the start script as expected:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtStartScript
seq(SbtStartScript.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)
```

However, I'd like to change the `start-script-name` setting (which is defined, confusingly, as `startScriptFile`) to write it to a different location, and this has been for more frustrating than I would expect it to be.

The setting shows up fine using `inspect`:

```
[ctdrest] $ inspect uses start-script-name
[info]
[info]  compile:start-script-for-jar
[info]  compile:start-script-not-defined
[ctdrest] $ inspect definitions start-script-name
[info]
[info]  *:start-script-name
[ctdrest] $ inspect tree start-script-name
[info] *:start-script-name = target/start
[info]   +-*:target = target
[info]     +-*:base-directory = /Users/amack/Coding/ctdrest
[info]       +-*:this-project = Project(id: CTDRestful, base: /Users/amack/Coding/ctdrest, aggreg..
[info]
```

But `sbt` complains when I try to set a value:

```
[ctdrest] $ set startScriptFile := "bar"
<set>:1: error: not found: value startScriptFile
startScriptFile := "bar"
^
<set>:1: error: reassignment to val
startScriptFile := "bar"
            ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

I presume I'm missing something screamingly obvious, but a whole lot of searching and examination of the SBT settings docs has not cleared anything up for me.

Comment: would you be willing to file a bug on GitHub about the name vs file discrepancy? should get fixed

Answer (score 1):

Fairly screamingly obvious. In this particular case, you can see from the source that the original key is defined in the nested object `StartScriptKeys`:

```
 object StartScriptKeys {
        val startScriptFile = SettingKey[File]("start-script-name")
        ...
 }
```

so the following does the trick:

```
[ctdrest] $ set StartScriptKeys.startScriptFile <<= target / "bar"
[info] Defining *:start-script-name
[info] The new value will be used by compile:start-script-for-jar, compile:start-script-not-defined
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to ctdrest (in build file:/Users/amack/Coding/ctdrest/)
```

This doesn't address the more general question of determining how to set a value if given a setting name such as `start-script-name` though. It seems SBT could be more helpful in this regard.

#### Edit

According to the [plugin design guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#use-a-nested-object) this would be handled more idiomatically by adding

```
import StartScriptKeys._
```

to `build.sbt`, and it is then possible to modify `startScriptFile` without the qualifier, although the qualifier is still required on the SBT console for some reason.

Comment: I would love to know the more general solution though. By [convention](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings.html#requested-dependencies), the Scala identifier is camel-cased, and the string representation is lower-cased and dash-separated. However, here the package maintainer has not quite followed this convention, and in addition the setting is defined in a nested object. I'm not sure how I could have worked out either of those without looking at the source code, which doesn't seem ideal. Is there really **no way** for SBT to tell me how set this setting?

Comment: I wonder if the nested object only needs to be specified because of the bug where the names don't match.  http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html recommends the nested keys object. sbt 0.13 works differently, the name is automatically computed from the Scala val name, so this bug becomes impossible.

Comment: @havoc-p - judging by the identical behaviour of `startScriptBaseDirectory`, which does follow the convention exactly, I don't think it's caused by the mismatch between the identifier and string.

Comment: @HavocP - On the plugin best practices page, it says users will need to import plugin keys in `build.sbt using eg "`import ObfuscateKeys._`". I didn't do the equivalent originally because I didn't think to read the plugin writing guide, which is the first place I've seen that (and it's still not clear how to work it out from SBT).